# Unable to add Safari developer certificate in safari

Tags: webdriver, browser-automation, safaridriver

Enviornment: Maz OSX
browser : safari
wedriver: 2.24.1

Created safari extension and safari developer certificate from apple developer site.
tried adding the certificate in safari keychain login .
As I open safari extension builder and try adding the extension, it shows "No Safari developer certificate".
In keychain it shows valid certificate, but its not getting reflected in safari.

Anyone came across this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got resolution ....

I had to add the safari developer certificate in "keychain access" >>  System

1 go to Keychain access

2 select  System  instead of login

3 select " Certificates"

4 drag and drop the certificate inside "Certificates". (It requires admin credentials, just ask ur system administrator )

5 now right click on the certificate added in keychain and select get info

6 select the "Trust" option and make all options always trust

And try to add the extension in safari extension builder, you will find the valid certificate

Comment: And a reminder when working on both PC and Mac - your certificate generated for Windows will not work on Mac. You need to get a new one.

Comment: For those who this didn't work for, another possible issue is that the Mac you're running on now may be a different Mac than the one where you created the original signing request. If so, you have to generate new certificates.   The reason OSX is not recognizing the Cert as yours is because it does not match the private-key on your system.